# Unitless line-heights is always better .. as eric meyer recommends

Tags: css

> That’s a pretty major difference. This
>   is why it’s always strongly
>   recommended that you use unitless
>   numbers if you’re going to set a
>   line-height  on something like the
>   html or body elements, or indeed on
>   any element that is going to have
>   descendant elements.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/

So now i will follow this suggestion.  but is there any cons to follow this?

Comment: Just don't follow his code examples of using pixel measurements for font sizes. Use points instead. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is there any cons to follow this?

I can't see any. The behaviour he describes:

> So what’s the difference? When you define a united value, like 1em, you’re setting things up to pass along the computed result to any descendants. For example, suppose the following CSS is applied to a document containing the following markup fragment:

Is usually what you want. There may be exceptions with some typographically very specialized designs with fixed `line-height` s to achieve some sort of effects. But that will be rare, and you'll recognize them when you see them.